# Better way for ' '|> Seq.isEmpty |> not'

Tags: f#

I am just wondering if there is a better way to write:

```
|> Seq.isEmpty |> not
```

Something like:

```
|> not Seq.isEmpty
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you like?

```
|> (not << Seq.isEmpty)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go with what you have at the moment. It depends on the context - when this is the result of some larger function, I think the following looks good:

```
let someFunction () = 
  someData
  |> Some pipeline
  |> Seq.isEmpty
  |> not
```

If I was writing this in some other context, I would most likely define a local variable and write something like this:

```
let local =    
  someData
  |> Some pipeline
if not (Seq.isEmpty local) then 
  printfn "Not empty!"
```

The idea in @Carsten's answer is nice too, but I would be bit worried that it might look weird to people who are not familiar with this coding pattern. Understanding what's going on there is not very easy, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say not. Instead, try to avoid functions like `Seq.isEmpty`, `Seq.head`, `Seq.skip` and so on when they undermine the lazyness or may lead to repeated enumeration of the sequence.
A prototypical implementation of `Seq.isEmpty` could be like

```
let isEmpty (xs : _ seq)=
    use en = xs.GetEnumerator()
    not <| en.MoveNext()
```

from which it is evident that in addition to its creation (and disposal) the enumerator has to advance itself once. An effort that will be repeated when you afterwards consume the sequence for good in case you have found it non-empty.

This could be mitigated by caching (`Seq.cache`), but you may ask as well if a sequence is still the right data structure for the task at hand.